# My cypher query where I count incoming relationship seems slow, need some help to improve performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Dear Cypher/Neo4j experts,

I have the following part of a graph where I have Countries, Cities, Companies and Projects modelled. I have the following Cypher query where I get the Country nodes, as well as the unique identifiers of the contained city nodes, a count of the LOCATED_IN and a count of the MAY_BE_EXECUTED_IN relationships

```
MATCH (country:Country)
OPTIONAL MATCH (country)-[:CONTAINS]->(city:City)
OPTIONAL MATCH (:Project)-[may_be_executed_in:MAY_BE_EXECUTED_IN]->(country)
OPTIONAL MATCH (:Company)-[located_in:LOCATED_IN]->(country)
RETURN DISTINCT country {.*
    , city: COLLECT(DISTINCT city.identifier)
    , MAY_BE_EXECUTED_IN_Count: COUNT(DISTINCT may_be_executed_in)
    , LOCATED_IN_Count: COUNT(DISTINCT located_in)
}
ORDER BY country.identifier ASCENDING
```

[image: graph extract]

There are 76 Country nodes and about 10000 Company nodes in the database. When I run the query it takes about 30 to 40 seconds, when I leave out the `MAY_BE_EXECUTED_IN_Count: COUNT(DISTINCT may_be_executed_in)` part the query completes in approx 40 milliseconds. I realize that the resources allocated to neo4j play a role, but my guess is that my query is not good. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

while doing more searching I found the answer, the query that I think i need is the following:

```
MATCH (country:Country)
OPTIONAL MATCH (country)-[:CONTAINS]->(city:City)
RETURN DISTINCT country {.*
  , city: COLLECT(DISTINCT city.identifier)
  , IS_SPECIAL_PROVISION_FOR_Count: size((:AnnouncementOfOpportunity)-[:IS_SPECIAL_PROVISION_FOR]->(country))
  , LOCATED_IN_Count: size((:Organization)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(country))
}
ORDER BY country.identifier ASCENDING
```

I make use of the `SIZE()` function to compute the number of relationships.

Comment: If all the starting nodes of the `IS_SPECIAL_PROVISION_FOR` relationship always have the `AnnouncementOfOpportunity` label, then it would be even faster to use `SIZE(()-[:IS_SPECIAL_PROVISION_FOR]->(country))`. Same thing for `LOCATED_IN` and `Organization`.